# Understanding Module details

Tags: google-breakpad

crash content:

Crash|SIGSEGV|0x0|0
Module|test||test|97D92A3F25F911B1F079955EACD08CB00|0x00400000|0x00418fff|1
Module|libm-2.23.so||libm-2.23.so|5EA278E1B26D9885588C03D898E44FD70|0x7f84fb863000|0x7f84fb96afff|0
Module|librt-2.28.so||librt-2.28.so|43AF109CEE1F83DEAD2A5F3958A6E3150|0x765e5000|0x765e9fff|0
Module|librbus.so.2.0.11||librbus.so.2.0.11|2C968AE0A11D0A1682AB2F27B458F79A0|0x765fb000|0x7661cfff|0

Hi
I would like to understand above details, having couple of doubts on that.

1. where we are getting this address "0x00400000|0x00418fff" ? (stack memory or default value address)
2. At end of module line , I could see that '1' and  '0' what is purpose of this?

anyone can explain one this please

thanks

At end of module line , I could see that '1' and  '0' what is purpose of this?